# How do I prove that the following function $f$ is continuous?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Let
$$f:\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x& \mbox{ if } ||x|| \le 1 \\ \frac{x}{||x||^2} & \mbox{ if } ||x|| \ge 1 \end{cases}$$

I am trying to use gluing lemma to prove this.

Let $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:||x|| \le 1\}$ and $B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x|| \ge  1\}$

$\mathbb{R}^n = A \cup B$

I am trying to show that $A$ is closed.

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $A$ converging to $a$ . We try to show that $||a|| \le 1$

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $||a|| \ge 1$

Then $||a - a_n|| < \epsilon , \mbox{ for all } n \ge N_{\epsilon} $ and $||a|| - ||a_n|| \le ||a-a_n||$

From this we can conclude that for every $\epsilon > 0$ , I can show that $||a|| \le 1 + \epsilon$
Then the only possible choice is $||a|| = 1$. Hence $a \in A$

I am trying to show that $B$ is closed.

Let $(b_n)$ be a sequence in $B$ converging to $b$ . We try to show that $||b|| \ge 1$

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $||b|| \le 1$

Then $||b_n - b|| < \epsilon , \mbox{ for all } n \ge N_{\epsilon} $ and $||b_n|| - ||b|| \le ||b-b_n||$

From this we can conclude that for every $\epsilon > 0$ , I can show that $||b|| \ge 1 + \epsilon$
Then the only possible choice is $||b|| = 1$. Hence $b \in B$

Hence $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A \cup B = \mathbb{R}^n$. Also we can show using the sequential criterion of continuity that $f_1:A \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous map and $f_2:B \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous map.

Hence, $f : A \cup B \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$ is a well-defined and continuous map.

So we are done.

Comment: Ya that looks right to me.

Comment: @RishiSonthalia Thanks :). Is there a significance to this problem?I am guessing it is mapping all the point from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a set $Y = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x|| \le 1\}$( a hemisphere) . Anything other than this?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind: the idea here is the essential one in (one standard method of) showing that $\Bbb{R}^n-0$ is homotopy equivalent to the sphere $S^{n-1}$.